# Wireguard server start issue

Tags: wireguard

When starting the server, Wireguard does not start. Log:

```
systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
wg-quick[1139]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
wg-quick[1139]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
wg-quick[1139]: [#] ip -4 address add 10.50.0.2/32 dev wg0
wg-quick[1139]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
wg-quick[1256]: [#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
wg-quick[1260]: resolvconf: Error: Run lock held by another process for longer than 10 seconds
wg-quick[1139]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
wg-quick[130477]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -4 address add 10.50.0.2/32 dev wg0
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
wg-quick[130509]: [#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
wg-quick[130477]: [#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -6 route add ::/0 dev wg0 table 51820
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -6 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -6 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
wg-quick[130577]: [#] ip6tables-restore -n
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
wg-quick[130477]: [#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
wg-quick[130477]: [#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
wg-quick[130596]: [#] iptables-restore -n
systemd[1]: Finished WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
```

sudo systemctl cat wg-quick@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for %I
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=wg-quick.target
Documentation=man:wg-quick(8)
Documentation=man:wg(8)
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wg-quick down %i
Environment=WG_ENDPOINT_RESOLUTION_RETRIES=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = key
Address = 10.50.0.2/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1


[Peer]
PublicKey = key
PresharedKey = key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = 132.132.132.132:48989
PersistentKeepalive=25
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable resolvconf in WireGuard Configuration:

```
DNS = off
```

This will prevent WireGuard from attempting to configure DNS settings using resolvconf.